# How Can i subtract two columns in different tables in SQL

Tags: sql, mysqli

I want to enter in a query the subtract between two columns in different tables it keeps saying error ...

```
SELECT FlightDate,
       Plane, 
       Destination,
       Capacity
FROM  
       FlightSchedule, 
       Routes, 
       Aircrafts
WHERE 
       FlightSchedule.RID=Routes.RouteID 
       AND FlightSchedule.Plane=Aircrafts.AcID 
       AND (SELECT SUM(Capacity) 
            FROM Aircrafts) 
            - 
           (SELECT Class , count(*) 
           FROM Tickets);
```

Comment: How you can substract class, Count(\*) from SUM(Capacity)? sum(capacity) -(class,Count(\*))

Comment: what is this condition ? AND 
(SELECT SUM(Capacity) FROM Aircrafts) - 
        (SELECT Class , count(*) FROM Tickets) ???

Comment: Well i have a project regarding database of an airline company and i want to make a query that shows that Capacity of a plane can subtract all buy tickets and in the view will show only tickets left to be bought

Comment: May you should try: `SELECT SUM(Capacity) FROM Aircrafts) - 
        (SELECT  count(*) FROM Tickets`

Comment: (SELECT SUM(Capacity) FROM Aircrafts) - 
        (SELECT Class , count(*) FROM Tickets)
Its a condition that i wanted to put but it shows error :/

Comment: Thanks a lot  @Jens but how can i show it as a new column in the view the subtraction ?

Comment: try `SELECT (SELECT SUM(Capacity) FROM Aircrafts) - 
        (SELECT Class , count(*) FROM Tickets)
,FlightDate,Plane, Destination,Capacity
FROM FlightSchedule,Routes,Aircrafts
WHERE  FlightSchedule.RID=Routes.RouteID AND FlightSchedule.Plane=Aircrafts.AcID 

;`

Answer (score 0):

The query is wrong on multiple levels.

First of all, you cannot put the details of SELECT capacity as a sub query under WHERE. The WHERE clause is for conditional parameters.

Try this:

```
WITH VACANCY as (SELECT SUM(Capacity) FROM Aircrafts) - (SELECT Count(*) FROM Tickets) 
SELECT FlightDate,Plane, Destination, Vacancy
FROM FlightSchedule,Routes,Aircrafts
WHERE  FlightSchedule.RID=Routes.RouteID AND FlightSchedule.Plane=Aircrafts.AcID;
```

You also need to a condition for the select count for tickets but I don't know the schema of tickets so...

Comment: thank you a lot ... I tried and it requires to enter a parameter value to Vacancy and after to V

Comment: Check this. I forgot the with clause earlier. You will need to add one condition for comparing the two subqueries in the WITH Clause so choose two parameters and add them in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

I would split this up into 2 parts. First get the data you need, then perform the math. You are also using old SQL syntax. You should re-format using the new JOIN syntax. It's also easier to read.

1st declare a table to hold you flight schedule and aircraft info.

```
Declare @AIRCRAFTCAPACITY Table
(
    [FlightDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Plane] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Destination] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Capacity] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [NoOfSeatsRemaining] [INT] NULL
);
```

Then insert the data you need.

```
INSERT @AIRCRAFTCAPACITY
(
    [FlightDate],
    [Plane],
    [Destination],
    [Capacity]
)
SELECT  FS.FlightDate,
        A.Plane, 
        FS.Destination,
        A.Capacity
FROM 
        FlightSchedule FS
INNER
JOIN    Routes R
ON
        FS.RID = R.RouteID
INNER
JOIN    Aircrafts A
ON
        FS.Plane = A.AcID
```

Now perform the math to calculate the remaining capacity. I've made an assumption that you are doing this for a particular route. But I'm sure you can adjust your SQL accordingly.

```
UPDATE  @AIRCRAFTCAPACITY
SET
        [NoOfSeatsRemaining] = [Capacity] - T.TICKETS_SOLD
FROM
        @AIRCRAFTCAPACITY A
INNER
JOIN    
        (
            SELECT ROUTEID, COUNT(ROUTEID) AS TICKETS_SOLD
            FROM
                   Tickets T1
            WHERE
                   T1.ROUTEID = A.ROUTEID
            GROUP
            BY     ROUTEID
        ) T
ON
        A.ROUTEID = T.ROUTEID
```

Apolgies if the syntax is a little off as it's hard to construct SQL when you dont have the underlying tables.

But hopefully it will help.